# How to block single user via nftables?

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, ipv6

I'm trying to setup a user, to run python applications without any
internet connection. But allow all other users to use the internet.

To ensure the "user", is quarantine from all activity. I'm use
"nfttables" on "Arch Linux".

My config looks like:

```
// user = blockbob 1007
nft -f ./blockhim.nft

table inet blockhim {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
        ct state established,related counter accept
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        ip protocol tcp meta skuid "blockbob" reject
    }
}

nft -s list ruleset

table inet filter {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
                ct state invalid drop comment "early drop of invalid connections"
                ct state { established, related } accept comment "allow tracked connections"
                iifname "lo" accept comment "allow from loopback"
                ip protocol icmp accept comment "allow icmp"
                meta l4proto ipv6-icmp accept comment "allow icmp v6"
                tcp dport 22 accept comment "allow sshd"
                meta pkttype host limit rate 5/second counter reject with icmpx admin-prohibited
                counter
        }

        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
        }
}
table inet blockhim {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
                ct state established,related counter accept
        }

        chain output {
                type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
                ip protocol tcp meta skuid 1007 reject with icmp port-unreachable
        }
}
```

I have a IPv6 and IPv4  LAN and WAN network on a Arch Linux 5.15.15-1-lts
and freshly installed "nftables"

Results

1. "OK USER" allowed all (e.g curl chrome) except for "PING" connections (e.g ping google.com)
2. "blockhim" all connections BLOCKED
3. Connection feel slightly delayed

Why is PING blocked and on "OK USER" with "IPV6 address Destination unreachable: Address unreachable" ?

Command "sudo nft -e flush ruleset" resets all back to normal.

Comment: Do you by any chance have IPv6 tunnel there? If yes - `meta pkttype host limit` rule may be at fault here.

Comment: Instead of running the python applications as a specific user, it might be simpler to run them inside a separate network namespace (that can be set up when that particular user logs in, or in some other way, depending on how you use the python applications).

Comment: Also, did you try without the previous filter table that is present in addition to the blockhim table? Looks like the experiment doesn't compare before adding blockhim vs after adding blockhim: it compares filter + blockhim vs nothing at all. If the "slow" behavior is already present with only inet filter present, it's not because of adding blockhim.